# How to preview geometry in Dynamo for Revit inside a custom node

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

this is for anyone familiar with Revit, Dynamo, or C#.

I'm trying to create a custom zero-touch node using C# that will highlight a chosen curve as colored geometry in the preview window, while remaining inside of a loop.

So far I can only preview geometry by returning it, and I can't apply a color to the geometry without using the Display.ByGeometry node on the canvas.

Here is the most sensible attempt at this I have so far, and it still doesn't work. The code runs without errors, but I also don't perceive any change on the display.

```
public static void ColorTest (Curve crv)
    {
        Cone cylinder = Cone.ByPointsRadii(crv.StartPoint, crv.EndPoint, 1, 1);
        DSCore.Color red = DSCore.Color.ByARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Display.Display.ByGeometryColor(cylinder, red);
        }
        temp.Dispose();
    }
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: one quick question @zarf.snackler - is the preview strictly in Dynamo or in a Dynamo viewer inside of Revit?

Comment: Well that's the thing, there are two viewers. The main Revit view, and also the Dynamo view window. Unless you have multiple screens it's usually impractical to interact with Dynamo and see the Revit view. Therefore I was trying to preview geometry in the Dynamo view. For more on this subject, check the forum discussion [here](https://forum.dynamobim.com/t/how-to-update-geometry-preview-and-then-dispose-of-geometry-inside-of-a-loop-c/8726).